# How to send HTML code with cURL?

Tags: php, html, curl

am struggling with this for weeks now..

what is the correct way to send HTML-code with `cURL` ??

I tried `base46_encode()` and also `json_encode()` .. but on the reciever-side I always get a unuseable string.. how would i encode a html-code for sending?

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
$payload = json_encode( $data );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));                
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );                
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array directly to cURL as documented on PHP.net, try turn the payload data into an array and send directly into cURL or via HTTP Build Query.

[HTTP Build Query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Possible duplicate of:
[PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)
and 
[Post HTML content via cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147565/post-html-content-via-curl)